# Firebase database security rule to access only user generated data with Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a chat support app model. I have only 1 agent and many requesting users asking queries. Each user can have multiple conversations with the agent (assume it like a whatsapp group having only 2 members, a user and that agent).

So I create a data structure like:

```
Conversation
-uId
-status
-conversationTitle
```

and for Messages,

```
Message
-conversationId
-message
-from //0 mean it from me to my friend and 1 for a message from my friend to me
-timestamp
```

Basic structure will be like:

```
Conversation1:{ "uId": "1", "status":0, "conversationTitle": "First conversation"},
Conversation2:{ "uId": "2", "status":0, "conversationTitle": "Second conversation"},
Conversation1:{ "uId": "1", "status":0, "conversationTitle": "Third conversation"}
```

and for messages:

```
    Message1: {"conversationId": "Conversation1", "message": "Hello there 1!", "from":0, "timestamp":******** },
    Message2: {"conversationId": "Conversation1", "message": "Hello there 2!", "from":0, "timestamp":******** },
    Message3: {"conversationId": "Conversation2", "message": "Hello there 3!", "from":0, "timestamp":******** },
    Message4: {"conversationId": "Conversation3", "message": "Hello there 4!", "from":0, "timestamp":******** },
```

As you can see Message 1 and 2 belong to Conversation 1 which in turn b belong to User 1 with uID 1.

I want all conversation that is happening with User 1 (uId: 1) and User 2 (uID: 2) must not be able to see conversations of 1.

I wrote security as:

```
"conversations":{
  "$uid":{
    ".read": "data.child('uId').val() == auth.uid",
    ".write":"auth != null && newData.child('uId').val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

and then in Android:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Query conversationsRef = database.getReference("conversations");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conversation, ConversationHolder> binderData = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conversation, ConversationHolder>(Conversation.class, R.layout.item_butler_converastions, ConversationHolder.class, conversationsRef) {
                    @Override
                    public void populateViewHolder(ConversationHolder chatMessageViewHolder, Conversation chatMessage, int position) {
                        chatMessageViewHolder.setName(chatMessage.getTitle());
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        super.onCancelled(error);
                    }
                };
```

When I do this I get permission error. I want to retrieve all conversation belonging to User 1.

I also tried using:

```
Query conversationsRef = database.getReference("conversations").orderByChild("uId").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

but didn't work. Thanks in advance.